# react native and firebase - firebase function as reference

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

Can someone explain why this code works:

```
this.firebaseRef.on('value', (snapshot) => {//...});
```

and this not:

```
const foo = this.firebaseRef.on;
foo('value', (snapshot) => {//...});
```

?

In react-native devtools debugger it throws an error: `Cannot read property 'Y' of undefined`

It's funny, because when I set a breakpoint and check it

```
foo === this.firebaseRef.on
```

it gives me true. `typeof foo` is a function. I don't get it. The same happens with `once`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is in what the `this` value will be when `on` is called. When functions are called as a member of an object, `this` is bound to the object. ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#As_an_object_method)) When function values are called as standalone variables, `this` is bound to the global object or `undefined` in strict mode. ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Simple_call))

In order to fix the problem, you must [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the function to the proper `this` value.

```
const foo = this.firebaseRef.on.bind(this.firebaseRef);
foo('value', (snapshot) => {
  // ...
});
```